# "questions of" or "questions on"

Tags: prepositions

Is the following sentence correct?

> Another main interest is political philosophy, especially questions **of** private property, authority, and capitalism.

Should I replace "questions of" with "questions on"?

Comment: I would prefer *about* or *regarding*.

Comment: I agree with @user3169 (I think _above_ is the better preposition). However, I wouldn't say that either _of_ or _on_ are "incorrect."

Comment: In this context "of" is correct, and I prefer it to "about" or "regarding". While I wouldn't say "on" is strictly incorrect I definitely wouldn't use it. "Questions of" parallels "matters of".

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "questions of" is fine in this context, as is @user3169 suggestion "questions regarding", or "questions about". As a native speaker, my instinct is that "questions of" is a more literary wording, and is more common in older documents. "Questions about" would be more conversational and less formal.

Some simple searching supports this. For example, a [search on Amazon for "question of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22question+of%22+site:amazon.com) will get you many book titles. Most of them are titles of serious, philosophical, or historical books, though there are a few exceptions. If you [search Amazon for "question regarding"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:amazon.com+%22question+regarding%22) or ["question about"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:amazon.com+%22question+about%22), you find people asking for help and suggestions, and you will not see many book titles.

The words "questions on" when talking about the question topics only sounds natural when you clearly say that they are the topics of the questions. As an example, in most contexts, it would be fine to write

> Another main interest is political philosophy, especially questions on the topics of private property, authority, and capitalism.

but "questions of" is shorter, and so is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds great! It is completely natural speech. You could say "questions about" but "questions of" sounds more formal, which is better for writing.